# How can I block embeds and show an individual preview image per block?

Tags: block-editor, embed, privacy

I am trying to program an **embed blocker for the default Gutenberg embeds** with a prior consent banner and preview image (for matters of privacy). In detail:

- block YouTube videos that are embedded via the Embed-Block (core/embed)
- replace them with a custom HTML banner
- including individual preview image per embed/block
- after consent show the embed as normal

So far I got a very good foundation with Borlabs Cookie plugin, that has some content blockers integrated from the start. For the moment I use the filters that the plugin is giving me, and customize the html and css. Now this is the crucial point: I want to show an *individual* preview image per embed.

**My current approach would be:**

1. Extend the core embed block with an image field, named e.g. "embed_preview_image". Great tutorial I found: https://awhitepixel.com/blog/add-custom-settings-to-existing-wordpress-gutenberg-blocks/ ...
2. Integrate a blocker with the `'embed_oembed_html'` filter (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/embed_oembed_html/) or just let Borlabs Cookie do the magic and customize the templates there with the plugin's filter...
3. In order to include the image from the custom field on the individual block I need access to the block data from the *current processed* block, within the filter. I thought of `parse_blocks()` but this is giving me all of the blocks, and then I would need some regex to sort out the right block... I think there must be a better way...(?)

So, is there a correlation between the oembed filter and the current parsed embed block or something? Or do you have some hint for me?

EDIT: Added my current code examples
EDIT 2: Updated code with native WP filters

**Use filter to modify output**

```php
/**
 * Show embed consent before embed is shown
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/embed_oembed_html/
 */
function edit_oembed_html($html, $url, $attr, $post_ID)
{   
    /** 
     * Replace embeds that are inserted via Gutenberg (Videos, Instagram, Twitter, etc.) with placeholder
     */

    // Default labels
    $description = 'Lorem ipsum...';
    $link_label = 'Link to...';

    // Default thumbnail
    $thumbnail = 'https://via.placeholder.com/800x450'; // Just a fallback

    // Check if the thumbnail should be individual per embed
    // if ( $this->embed->embed_blocker_thumbnail ) { // PSEUDO CODE

        // ISSUE: Here I want to get an individual preview image for that specific current embed
        // $thumbnail = $this->embed->embed_blocker_thumbnail[src]... PSEUDO CODE

    //}

    // Build HTML template
    $html = '
        <div class="v4core_embed_blocker">
            <div class="v4core_embed_blocker_content_wrap">
                <img class="v4core_embed_blocker_thumbnail" src="'. $thumbnail .'" alt="'. $name .'">
                <div class="v4core_embed_blocker_content">
                    <span class="wp-caption-text v4core_embed_blocker_description">'. $description .'<br/><a class="v4core_embed_blocker_link" href="'. $url .'" target="_blank">'. $link_label .'</a></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>';

    // Return it
    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'embed_oembed_html', 'edit_oembed_html', 10, 4);
```

Comment: The embed block just uses OEmbed, which has been around in WordPress for a long time. Could you not replace the markup with a HTML banner in PHP using the oembed filters? I don't see why there needs to be javascript involved, the JS in the core block fetches the same HTML using the same system

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes, I used the oembed filter for that in another project and everything is fine with that as long as a global preview image is used: Hook into oembed, replace it with HTML banner, get the preview image from an acf field anywhere in custom theme settings and show it. But with this approach the preview image is equal for all embeds.

What I am looking for is an individual preview image: So embed "A" has preview image "A", and embed "B" has preview image "B" etc. For now I thought of the given approach above, but I am stuck at the point where l can inject the custom image...

Comment: You can still do that using the OEmbed filters

Comment: I've taken a look at the code you added to the question, but nowhere do I see anything related to WordPress core filters or blocks. This appears to be a Borlabs cookie plugin question https://borlabs.io/borlabs-cookie/, you need to ask their support, 3rd party plugin dev support is off topic here ( also, nobody would have been able to provide a working answer without knowing you were relying on that plugin )

Comment: @TomJNowell I understand your point and have updated the code with native WP filters. For me the core issue stays the same, and if it is possible to achieve with only the oembed filters, I honestly don't know how to proceed for an individual embed placeholder image. Maybe I am overlooking something, I don't know...

Comment: how would you determine what the image should be for a given embed? Note that `get_field` is an ACF wrapper around `get_post_meta`, and it assumes the post ID is the current post, but that might not be true, you should give it the `$post_ID` the filter passes you

Comment: @TomJNowell Currently the `get_field` line is my fallback, because this just gets me an image that is only once and globally defined. So, to determine an individual image for a given embed (that is separate for every embed) I thought I extend the core/embed block with an additional field e. g., and then in the filter I can access that image from this field. But this is just a "thought experiment", I don't know if it would even be possible to access that image field with the filter.

Comment: Could you re-open my question? Or is there something else that's not ok?

Comment: I've reopened but note that this must be pure WP, if it doesn't work with that plugin then that's the plugins problem

Comment: Ok, I edited the code to pure WP